# Destructuring hybrid array-objects returned by String.matchAll

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, destructuring

**String.matchAll** yields hybrid arrays with added properties - index, input, and groups.

E.g.

```
[...'abc'.matchAll(/a|b|c/g)]
```

yields:

```
0: ['a', index: 0, input: 'abc', groups: undefined]
1: ['b', index: 1, input: 'abc', groups: undefined]
2: ['c', index: 2, input: 'abc', groups: undefined]
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Is there a way to destructure matchAll results in an arrow function in Array.map or Array.filter?

A more generic Q: how to destructure "hybrid arrays" in arrow functions, when both elements and properties of the array are required.

I can destructure matchAll in **for-of** cycle:

```
for (const {0: m, index, input} of 'abc'.matchAll(/a|b|c/g)) {
   console.log(m, index, input)
}

a 0 abc
b 1 abc
c 2 abc
```

--I cannot find a way to destructure it in a .map function:

```
[...'abc'.matchAll(/a|b|c/g)].map({0: m, index, input} => m)
```

--gives an **Uncaught SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list** error

```
[...'abc'.matchAll(/a|b|c/g)].map({0: m, index, input} => m)
```

**UPDATE. Thanx to @Konrad. A destructuring object literal should be placed in parentheses:**

```
[...'abc'.matchAll(/a|b|c/g)].map( ( {0: m, index, input} ) => m)
```

A more elaborate example:

```
    [...'abc'.matchAll( /a|b|c/g )].map( ({0: m, index, input}) => 
`${ input.substring(0, index) }[${ m }]${ input.substring( index + m.length ) }`)
```

Yields:

```
0: "[a]bc"
​1: "a[b]c"
​2: "ab[c]"
```

Answer (score -1):

Missing parentheses

```js
console.log(
  [...'abc'.matchAll(/a|b|c/g)].map(({0: m, index, input}) => m)
)
```